# How to solve the first order differential equation $y'+5y=-3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is: 
solve the first order differential equation: 
$$y'+5y=-3,\\y(0)=1.$$

Here is my work so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjsa5.jpg
Can anyone verify if it's correct and tips on simplifying?

Comment: Distribute the denominator so that you have $-\frac{3}{5}+ce^{-5t}$. Then plug in t=0 to find the value of c. Your work seems good so far.

Comment: @Displayname Thank you! Would C be equal to 1 though if y(0) = 1, making the final answer -3/5 + e^-5t?

Comment: You have $-\frac{3}{5}+ce^{-5t}=1$. Plugging in $t=0$, $-\frac{3}{5}+c=1$ or $c=\frac{8}{5}$.

Comment: Your link is dead. Please upload the image using the official image uploader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'(x)+5y=-3$$
Multiply by the integrating factor $e^{5x}$ and integrate both sides:
$$\int y'e^{5x}+5e^{5x}y = \int -3e^{5x}$$
or $$ye^{5x} = -\frac{3}{5}e^{5x}+C$$
which gives $$y(x)=-\frac{3}{5} + \frac{C}{e^{5x}}$$
subbing in $y(0)=1$ yields $$y(0)=-\frac{3}{5}+C = 1$$
or $$C = \frac{8}{5}$$
so your final solution is $$y(x)=-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{8}{5e^{5x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
y'(x) + 5x + 3 = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad y(x) = -\frac{3}{5} + c_{1}  e^{-5x}
$$

$$
y(0) = 1 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad y(x) = \frac{1}{5} \left(-3 + 8e^{-5x} \right)
$$

[image: y]